# No redirect rules processed

Tags: angular, redirect, netlify

I'm making an Angular web application (mostly based on [this StackOverflow post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120571/netlify-ng-command-not-found), but for some reason Netlify won't find my redirects, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong. The reason I know why Netlify doesn't find my redirects is because it literally outputs the message `No redirect rules processed`.

I added `_redirects.txt` with the following context:

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Then I added my file as an asset to Angular.

```json
            "assets": [
              ... ,
              "src/_redirects.txt" // I also tried removing `.txt`, but file gets find in both cases.
            ],
```

I first build locally to see if my file gets included in my build. Which it does. It also gets found in my Netlify deployment (I downloaded and manually confirmed multiple times).

**I also tried following things**

- Add `http://worthashot.netlify.com/* https://worthashot.netlify.com/:splat 301!` as first line of my `_redirects.txt` file, according to StackOverflow post [Netlify redirect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201224/netlify-redirect-not-working).
- Have no file type for my `_redirects` file. However, I found on [Netlify documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/) that is must be text file.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst creating this question as in-depth as possible. I noticed the following message in Netlify

```
3 new files uploaded

   1 generated page and 2 assets changed.

   New pages include:

   count-your-drinks/index.html
```

So I thought that it had something to do with my deployment folder (`count-your-drinks` is my project name in kebab case). I reviewed my Netlify build settings and I saw that the build folder was set to `dist/count-your-drinks`. I changed this to `dist`.

I also updated my `angular.json`'s `outputPath` from `dist/count-your-drinks` to `dist`.

This solved my issue.